# jQuery function doesn't work when scrolling the page

Tags: jquery

I use the function at the top of the page to show span on mouse click:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#contact').click(function() {
        $(this).find('span').text( $(this).data('last') );
    });
});
```

And this work untill I scroll the page into the footer. Than when I move up and click again, the function doesn't work. 
How to make this function work once per session or per page load?

Comment: there is nothing in your code that should break if you scroll. There must be other code that does something when you reach the footer

Comment: function($) -> that was strange. try this
`$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click','#contact',function() {
        $(this).find('span').text( $(this).data('last') );
    });
});`

Comment: Is there another part of your code that removes the `#contact` element? Possibly when you reach the footer? If so, the click event must be re-bound after re-adding `#contact`. Do you see any errors in the developer console?

Comment: @Pete maybye he load DOM again or do something weird, then if you callback to documet on event, then you know that will works on 100%

Comment: @Pete No errors in the console regarding this. There is only 'Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.facebook.com" from accessing a frame' but i guess that's not the problem.

Comment: @Pete No. There's fixed header at the top which shows up when scrolling the page. It happens when this header shows up.

Comment: @Pete No. It doesn't.

Comment: @Pete I can give you a link to the website somehow if it's possible

Comment: @Pete https://multimed.pl/o-multi-med/ at the top where the phone with double XX is

Comment: Yeah, your phone number is being removed so you need to delegate the event as in the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you scroll down and then up, verify if the `#contact` element still exists. If yes, check if the `span` inside still exists as well and the attr `data-last`.

You might have something that breaks your function to work.

Besides that your code looks good, but can be written better.

That $ sign inside function($) is weird...

If you manipulate `#contact`, try to add an event delegate with `$(document).on([method], [element])`, that will listen `#contact` even if it is manipulated.

```
//jQuery = $ sign
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click','#contact', function() {
        $(this).find('span').text( $(this).data('last') );
    });
});
```

**2nd solution** - if you have some conflicts with jQuery library
stay with jQuery instead of $

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(document).on('click','#contact', function() {
        $(this).find('span').text( $(this).data('last') );
    });
});
```

Comment: why -1 ... can you explain

Comment: ...what is this answer

Comment: When I use this code I get: TypeError: $ is not a function. (In '$(document)', '$' is undefined) in the console.

Comment: Do you have jQuery on your project? What plugins are you using? You might have some conflicts with jQuery library. that's why you had function($)... check my answer again with 2nd solution

Comment: @Sandrina Pereira, Thanks a lot. Second solution is working great :)